# Display html within @html.actionlink with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap, and trying to make my links ASP.Net MVC look nice.

However, the <i class=... in the link below, is html encoded, rather than being sent as html to the browser:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("<i class='icon-user icon-white'></i> Create New", "Create", "", New With {Key .class="btn btn-primary"} )
```

[image: How button appers]

Is there any way of keeping the <i class=... as html, so that the button displays correctly?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Instead of using `@Html.ActionLink()`, just write out the `<a>` tag yourself. You can use `@Url.Action()` to get the URL of an action for your HREF attribute.

The `@Html` helpers are nice, but they won't always provide the flexibility you need.

Answer (score 16):

I was dealing with the same issue, but wanted to keep using a helper, because I was making an Ajax button.

I ended up with these two helper methods, one for each helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString IconActionLink(this AjaxHelper helper, string icon, string text, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var builder = new TagBuilder("i");
    builder.MergeAttribute("class", icon);
    var link = helper.ActionLink("[replaceme] " + text, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, ajaxOptions, htmlAttributes).ToHtmlString();
    return new MvcHtmlString(link.Replace("[replaceme]", builder.ToString()));
}

public static MvcHtmlString IconActionLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string icon, string text, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var builder = new TagBuilder("i");
    builder.MergeAttribute("class", icon);
    var link = helper.ActionLink("[replaceme] " + text, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes).ToHtmlString();
    return new MvcHtmlString(link.Replace("[replaceme]", builder.ToString()));
}
```

Just throw them in a static class in your project, compile and you should see them (You may need to add an using statement on your page).

When using the helper you can use "icon-plus" or even "icon-plus icon-white" for the icon string.

Comment: Definitely this answer should be marked as best one.

Answer (score 4):

***3-Step Solution:***

**1. Create this HtmlExtensions class:**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ActionButton(this HtmlHelper html, string linkText, string action, string controllerName, string iconClass)
    {
        //<a href="/@lLink.ControllerName/@lLink.ActionName" title="@lLink.LinkText"><i class="@lLink.IconClass"></i><span class="">@lLink.LinkText</span></a>
        var lURL = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);

        // build the <span class="">@lLink.LinkText</span> tag
        var lSpanBuilder = new TagBuilder("span");
        lSpanBuilder.MergeAttribute("class", "");
        lSpanBuilder.SetInnerText(linkText);
        string lSpanHtml = lSpanBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        // build the <i class="@lLink.IconClass"></i> tag
        var lIconBuilder = new TagBuilder("i");
        lIconBuilder.MergeAttribute("class", iconClass);
        string lIconHtml = lIconBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        // build the <a href="@lLink.ControllerName/@lLink.ActionName" title="@lLink.LinkText">...</a> tag
        var lAnchorBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
        lAnchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", lURL.Action(action, controllerName));
        lAnchorBuilder.InnerHtml = lIconHtml + lSpanHtml; // include the <i> and <span> tags inside
        string lAnchorHtml = lAnchorBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(lAnchorHtml);
    }
}
```

**2. Add this using at your View**

```
@using Extensions
```

**3. And simple call when you need**

```
@: <li class="btn btn-mini btn-inverse"> @Html.ActionButton(lLink.LinkText, lLink.ActionName, lLink.ControllerName, lLink.IconClass)</li>
```

Comment: This is overkill.

Answer (score 4):

Use [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/).

It works with intellisense, allows for fluent syntax and you can write something like this with it:

```
@(Html.Bootstrap().ActionLinkButton("Create New", "Create")
    .IconPrepend(Icons.user, true)
    .Style(ButtonStyle.Primary))
```

Parameter `true` in the `IconPrepend` is for white icon type.

Besides, it's got a lot more very useful helpers.

---

Disclaimer: I'm the author of TwitterBootstrapMVC

Use of this library for Bootstrap 3 is not free.

Comment: FYI, TwitterBootstrapMVC is no longer free for developers using Bootstrap 3, as they now charge a licence fee if you are a individual or organizational developer.

Comment: I can just recommend not to use the Html Helpers at all just raw Jquery which means 100% flexibility...

Answer (score 4):

```
@Html.ActionLink(" New", "Create", "", new { @class="icon"} )
```

In css style:

```
.icon:before{
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f055";
}
```

Comment: I had to add the following to make this work. 
    @font-face {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    src: url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2);
    }

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Employee")" class="btn btn-primary">Index</a>
```

Comment: Could you expand and justify your answer? Why is it a good answer?

Answer (score 2):

@Html.ActionLink("Link Title", "ActionName", "ControllerName", New With {.id = Model.id }, **New With {.class = Html.Raw("btn btn-primary btn-mini")}**)

This HTML.AcionLink overload allows you to add attributess to the rendered html - remember to pass null/nothing for the needed parameters in this overload.

Comment: This won't affect the text that is displayed for the link, which was what the question was about.

Answer (score 1):

For any ASP.NET user this is how it worked for me:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Catalog_Users", new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })%>
```

The shown text will be: Cancel.
The ActionResult will be Index and Catalog_Users is the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Though this question is old, but I still though of providing a simpler solution. At first, I thought its so difficult to achieve this but its so simple.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionMethod", "Controller",)" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Chart</a>
```

@Url.Action() give the same power as that of Html.ActionLink. See below image (top button is exactly the way you're using it, while the bottom button is the solution to the problem.

[image: using html code in MVC Html.Action function]

Answer (score 0):

I like G Jeny Remirez's answer. I just want to expand on this a bit. It's important that you use a four argumnent actionlink to include the class. So, if you just want to redirect to the same controller, but a different action, it's:

```
@Html.ActionLink("cancel", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn" })
```

Or if you want to redirect to the same controller with some parameters:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", new { param1 = ViewBag.param1, input = "activity" }, new { @class = "btn" })
```